# Using fgrep with .txt as argument

Tags: grep

Sorry if it is a duplicate, but I really couldn't find an answer.

How could I solve this one: I have a base .txt file (base.txt), and I want to perform the command *"cat base.txt | fgrep string_to_find.txt"*, where string_to_find.txt contains the string I want to use with fgrep. I have a lot of string_to_find.txt files, so I can't do it one by one manually, I have to automate the task, most probably with a bash script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the .txt file contains exactly the string I want to search, just solved with *cat base.txt | fgrep "$(cat string_to_find.txt)"*.